# How can I use Code Contracts in a C++/CLI project?

Tags: msbuild, c++-cli, code-contracts

I recently stumbled upon Code Contracts and have started using them in my C# projects. However, I also have a number of projects written in C++/CLI.

For C# and VB, Code Contracts offer a handy configuration panel in the project properties dialog. For a C++/CLI project, there is no such panel.

From the documentation, I got the impression that adding Code Contracts support to a C++/CLI project should be a simple matter of calling some external tools as part of the build process (namely `ccrefgen.exe`, `cccheck.exe`, and `ccrewrite.exe`). However, the number of command line options and restrictions concerning the call sequence have me somewhat intimidated.

Can anybody point me to a simple way to run the Code Contracts tools as an automated part of the build process in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

I arrived at this stackoverflow page because I am searching for the same answers that the original poster is looking for.  So far, my searches seem to indicate that "Code Contracts" per se are not available for C++ native code.  However, there is something similar called "VC++ (Visual C++) source annotations".

Try the following links:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/code-contracts.aspx#visual-c-source-annotations

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstscode/thread/db48da4d-fc93-4e99-99cc-22d47c5838e9

Comment: Hi que que, Code Contracts are designed to work only with managed code. They work with C# and VB; they can potentially work with C++/CLI; they cannot work with native C++.
My original question was about support for C++/CLI. For native C++, your answer might be a good solution.